# Is it possible to dynamically include a shared object based on the computer architecture using a .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a QT application with a coworker. My particular part of this application requires the use of a third party library. Since we only need a small part of this library, we decided to make a .so file to be included with our project to avoid unnecessarily transferring files to our repository. We recently ran into trouble though when we were reminded that since we have different architectures (32-bit versus 64-bit), the .so file was basically useless. Since we had these .so files, is it possible to include both of these and, when the project is built, to dynamically detect what architecture it is building on and include the appropriate shared object file?

The part I can't figure out is recognizing the architecture in a .pro file. I've found this answer on the [qt forums](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_detect_in_the_.pro_file_if_i_am_compiling_for_a_32_bit_or_a_64_bi), but as someone commented, this solution is only available on windows. I've also found suggestions on using the environment variable $MACHTYPE to detect architecture, but if I'm not mistaken, that is a linux only solution. Is there a truely cross-platform method of detecting the architecture?

We've also considered just packaging the tarball of the third party library source with the application, but we deemed it 'not user friendly' to ask the user to compile the library themselves before they can use our program. We agreed that if possible, this program should be as standalone as possible. Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing much the same thing right now. Qt SDK 1.2 has QMAKE_HOST.arch

```
contains( QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64 ) {
   LIBS += 64bitlib.a
}
else {
   LIBS += 32bitlib.a
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have looked into using QMAKE_HOST.arch, but in my link above, it says this solution is windows only?

Comment: No clue why they would say that. It works for me on 64 bit Ubuntu and 32 bit Win7. ETA:
I see why now, they have "win32-msvc*:" as part of the rule. Note that my example above does not have that.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. We wrote it off because of that comment about it being Windows only. Thanks for your help!